# adding creation time to a files filename

Tags: python-3.x

So far I have the following:

```
source_folder = 'file_location'
for file in os.listdir(source_folder):
    if file.startswith('stnet_'):
        os.rename(file, file.replace('stnet_a_b', '%s_' % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file)) + 'stnet_a_b'))
```

The issue with is is I keep getting FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified 'stnet_a_b.raw'

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `os.listdir` can only get the filenames without directory, while `os.rename` needs full name with directory. you can use `os.path.join(dir, filename)`. and if you are on Windows you must make sure filename doesn't contain special characters which your code contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` can only get the filenames **without** directory, while `os.rename`, `os.path.getctime` needs **full** name with directory(if your current directory is not conincidently file_location then the file will not be found). 
You can use `os.path.join` to get the full name. And if you are on Windows you must make sure filename doesn't contain special characters which your code contains.

```
dir = r'file_location'
# os.chdir(dir) # in case you don't want to use os.path.join
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
print(filename)
if filename.startswith('stnet_'):
    src = os.path.join(dir, filename)
    ctime_str = str(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(src)))
    ctime_str = ctime_str.replace(':', '').replace(' ', '')  # remove special characters
    fn_new = filename.replace('stnet_a_b',
                              '{}_'.format(ctime_str + 'stnet_a_b'))
    des = os.path.join(dir, fn_new)
    print('src={}, des={}'.format(src, des))
    os.rename(src, des)
```

please try above code.

Comment: @ Lei Yang This works fine, thanks for the help and explanation!